# how to call a method async in meteor if having load of data while fetching server side

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

hello i have a server side method i am calling this method from client side.the method works fine.but when i return my query result.then it does not show in client side. but when i return something like 'hello' then it shows in client side. the issue is that my query is taking long time to execute. if anyone have idea to get response of query in my client side code.below i added my code.

```
Meteor.methods({
    getResponseFromServer:function(latlong){




        lng = parseFloat(latlong.lng);

        lat = parseFloat(latlong.lat);

        //return 'hello';
        //this hello i got in my client side code.

        console.log(Centers.find({ coordinates: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lat,lng] }, $maxDistance: 10000 } } }).fetch());
        //getting data from server



        var getObject = Centers.find({ coordinates: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lat,lng] }, $maxDistance: 10000 } } }).fetch();
        //getting data from server and store it in an object and return it

        return getObject;





        }


});
```

and i have my client side code simple.

```
Template.searchlist.onRendered(function(){

    this.searchedString = Router.current().params.name;
    searchedParams = this.searchedString;
    searchedParams = searchedParams.split('-');
    var lat = searchedParams.pop();
    var lng = searchedParams.pop(1);

    lng = Number(lng).toFixed(6);
    console.log(lng);
    lat = Number(lat).toFixed(6);
    var latlong = {'lat':lat,'lng':lng};


    Meteor.call("getResponseFromServer",latlong,function(error,success){
        console.log(error+' see sucess here');
        console.log(success+' see failure here');
    });

});
```

please give me solution about it if anyone have idea.

Comment: Why are you using a method instead of pub-sub here?

Comment: sorry @MichelFloyd  i don't understand what you mean by pub-sub. i have to use a server side method for $near operator which is not supported by minimongo.

Comment: have you tried returning just the cursor? (ie. not calling `.fetch()`). Might also help to check in the network tab of devtools for the data passed between server and client to see if there is any reply

Comment: @ Frederick Stark i solved the problem console.log(success); i got my response from server. thank you for your afforts

Comment: @ShaktiSisodiya If you have found a solution , please answer your question , so that it is helpful to others as well.